# Is there software to automatically add subtitles to the videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, vlc, video-player, subtitle, translation

I am looking for a software or media player that has subtitles automatically.
For example with VLC, if I do not have the subtitle file, I can not have the subtitles.

Is there any software that allows me to translate English subtitles to Spanish automatically?

Comment: Media centers like Kodi can try to download subtitles; Emby server also does that; maybe there are simpler media players that can do it too but I'm not aware of any. Also the above examples need proper settings but it's easy. But if you're looking for automated translation I don't think there's one. The software I mentioned work by downloading subtitle files from known websites like opensubtitles.org.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielaGarcia for the contribution. Which of the two is the one that works when downloading the files? What you mention is a player or a translator? Thank you.
What I want is to be able to put subtitles, either one way or another, maybe I should not put in the question "automatically"

Comment: Kodi and Emby is what I use. Both require settings for it and if using the opensutitles.org service you also need to create an account. It is not a translator in any case. It merely searches the databases with the file title and/or metadata and if there are subtitles available for the chosen language it'll download and use them. If there aren't it won't, of course. Here's an example for Kodi: https://kodisubtitles.net/

Comment: Hello @GabrielaGarcia, how do you have the installation, do you have Kodi to watch the videos and EMMM use it as a server? Should you configure one with another for the subtitle download to work? Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the idea @GabrielaGarcia. use Kodi, but I can not find the subtitles in Spanish anywhere. I'm frustrated because I need it to watch the videos of a course in which I'm interested. Thank you

Comment: If there are no subtitles available in the websites that provide them then there's nothing to do. I've been saying since the beginning that what you want - an automatic translator - doesn't exist. What exists is plugins for media players that can automate the some process that otherwise you would do manually - download a subtitles file.

Comment: I have same issue, configured `kodi` to automatically download subtitles either in native language, or in English when native not available. This way its possible to learn English :) However subtitles are not always available in any language.

Answer (score 2):

**VLSub - A VLC extension for adding subtitles to videos**

VLC has an extension called [VLSub](https://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/VLSub+0.9.13?content=148752) which allows you to download and add subtitles to your videos.

The package is called `vlc-plugin-sub` which you can find either in Software Manager or you can install the package from the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) with the command: `sudo apt install vlc-plugin-sub`.

Optionally, you could install it manually, either from the above VideoLan link, or from the [developer's repository on GitHub](https://github.com/exebetche/vlsub):

1. Click on the download link (located on the files tab on the VideoLan site).
2. Save the file, extract `vlsub.lua` and save it in either of the two following directories:

   (all users): `/usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/`

   (current user): `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/`

This plugin downloads subtitles from the site [opensubtitles.org](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/subs). These are user-submitted files. So, subtitles for a particular video may sometimes not be available or out of sync with the particular version of your video.

**VLSub usage:**

1. Once the extension is installed, Select *View*-->*VLSub*-->*Research* from the VLC menu.
2. You will be presented will a dialog box like the following:

   [image]
3. Search by *Name*, *hash* or any additional details you may want to add.
4. Select *Download Selection*. This will download your selection(usually an .srt file) to the same directory as the video and start using the subtitle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this workaround, uploading to YouTube, is useful for someone. YouTube creates subtitles for the original language of the video and translates, but the translation is only from English to other languages, the opposite is apparently not available (step 9-10).

***1. Upload your video to youtube:*** 
[image]

***2. In "Advanced settings" tab - "Video language" define the original (if you want to translate, the original may have to be english)***:
[image]

***3. Enter your channel***:

[image]

***4. Enter YouTube studio***:

[image]

***5. To the left side, click on Videos, and select your video.***

***6. Having your video opened (important - step 5), click on Transcriptions on the left side, and on the right side click ADD LANGUAGE blue button:***
[image]

***7. to the right side click ADD, blue square with arrow:***
[image]

***8. To the right side click on "Create New subtitles or CC":***
[image]

***9 and 10. click up left in "Autotranslate" and then to the right "save changes" (important):***
[image]

***11. click in the language of interest, translated in step 10; click in Actions, now you can choose the desired format. for ex. .srt (.srt is not available in step 9)***

***12. There might be significant overlap among sentences. I use [Gaupol](https://otsaloma.io/gaupol/) [(link to install)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gaupol) to reduce that: (Tools menu - Adjust Durations)***

[image]

***13. Now, use MKVToolNix (has GUI) or HandBrake to add subtitles to video.***

Example: (command line version)

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui
mkvmerge -o outputfile.mkv inputfile.mp4 subtitle.srt
```